# how can I test a remember me feature using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, session-cookies, chrome-options

how can I write a test case validation for a remember me button as selenium every time opens a new instance of the browser with no cookies.
I heard ChromeOptions class can store cookies in a private file.
I tried searching for the argument and found-
`"user-data-dir=/path/"`

how can I use this path back into my next test case in order to validate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your second loop

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
```

You may or may not then also need to re-instantiate the driver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
```

and do the GET request

```
 driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/route_that_requires_remember_me")
```